# How do I add multiple buttons to JFrame?

Tags: java, button, jframe

I need something really basic. 
I tried this:

```
import java.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class thisthing
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            JButton button= new JButton("Add Interest");
            frame.add(button);
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Other Button");
            frame.add(button1);

            class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("hello, I was pressed");
                }
            }
            class OtherButtonListener implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("The Other button was pressed");
                }
            }

            ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
            button.addActionListener(listener);
            ActionListener listener1 = new OtherButtonListener();
            button1.addActionListener(listener1);

            frame.setSize(100, 100);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But then my computer had trouble making two buttons on one window when I ran it, so it tried to make two windows. I really don't know how to describe it except to  say that it was a mess and I did something wrong. 
In the end I need to add 15 buttons in a triangle shape (the famous AP peg game project)..so is there any way I can also re-position the buttons and mess with their sizes?

Comment: "My computer crashed" is not an accurate description i hope :) Read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your computer crashed? Really? no. It did not, or you have a hardware fault. Maybe your program aborted with an error. Process isolation makes it impossible for a program to crash a whole computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either (recommended) use another layoutmanager (or define one on your own). Or (really NOT recommended and extremely ugly solution, but it works):

```
frame.setLayout(null);

JButton button = new JButton("Hello world");
button.setBounds(20 , 20 , 100 , 30);
frame.add(button);
```

this will position the button at the given location and with the given size. Alternatively you could use 

`button.setSize(100 , 30);
button.setLocation(20 , 20);`

Note: without a layoutmanager, you can position your components freely, but they will by default have the bounds (0 , 0 , 0 , 0), so you will always have to set the position and size to get anything visible. I only provide this solution because you asked for it, you shouldn't use it though.